# Webpage download

Tags: c#

I am having some issues download the source of a webpage, I can view the webpage fine in any browser, I can also run a web spider and download the first page no problem. Whenever I run the code to grab the source of that page I always get 403 forbidden error.

As soon as the request is sent the 403 forbidden error is returned. Anyone have any ideas?

```
string urlAddress = "http://www.brownells.com/";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
      Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
      StreamReader readStream = null;

.................................

      response.Close();
      readStream.Close();
```

Comment: There's a pretty fair chance they're doing some sort of trick to detect spidering. As such, there's no particularly general help SO can give, only ways to evade a specific host's protections, which doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If you're in a rush...

```
string uri =  @"http://brownells.com";

HttpWebRequest request         = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
request.UserAgent              = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36";
request.Accept                 = @"text/html";

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (Stream stream            = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader      = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    Console.WriteLine (reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

`request.AutomaticDecompression` notifies the server that we, the client, support both `gzip` and `Deflate` compression schemes, so there'll be some performance gain there, however it isn't needed, the server only required that you have your `UserAgent` and `Accept` header set.

---

#### The tools for the job...

Remember, if you can do it in a browser, you can do it in C#, the only time you'll seriously struggle is if there's some JavaScript sorcery where the site is setting cookies using JavaScript, it's rare, but it happens.

Back to the topic at hand...

1. Download [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), it's a web debugging proxy that's simply invaluable when debugging HTTP traffic. Install it and run it.
2. Navigate to your website of choice.
3. Check out fiddler to see the request your browser sent then check out what the server responded with...
4. Replicate it using C#

[Link to the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqg6E.png)
[image]

---

## Edit

If you want to dump to a file, you need to use a filestream

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (Stream stream            = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader      = new StreamReader(stream))
using (TextWriter writer        = new StreamWriter("filePath.html") 
{
    writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Aydin.  Using what you posted I no longer get the 403 error, but there is still something missing.  When I dump the page to a file I get this content from the stream into the text file (System.IO.StreamReader) I had not seen this before.  I am going to use Fiddler and see what I can figure out.  Thanks again.

Comment: I've added a method to show you how to do just that as well

Comment: How in the heck did I overlook that?  I was missing the ReadToEnd() once I added it in everything is working fine.  Thanks again for the invaluable help Aydin.